# Feature Selection Process For Regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science

I am trying to solve a regression problem (determine next month expected revenue).I came to know about different feature selection technique like

1. Filter Method
2. Wrapper Method
3. Embedded Method

Q1: Now the problem is, i think those methods are for classification type problem. So how can we use feature selection for regression problem?

Q2: I came to know about "Regularization". Is it the only way to use feature selection for regression problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know these filter selections you mentioned, but you can use:

- Scikit-learn.selection_feature.RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination) 
  or
- Scikit-learn.selection_feature.PCA (Principal Component Analisys)

I'm pretty sure you can use them for classification or regression.

Here's an example of use of RFE and LinearRegression: https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-with-pandas-e3690ad8504b